# How can I use universal and existential quantification in julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump, ijulia-notebook, julia-studio

I want to code domination definition in Julia. `x dom y`. x , y are 2 vectors.

`b=all(x<=y) &&  any(x<y)`

would you please help me. How can I code this concept in Julia?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach can be almost like you have specified it:

```
dom(x, y) = all(x .<= y) && any(x .< y)
```

You could also use a loop e.g. like this:

```
function dom(x::AbstractVector, y::AbstractVector)
    @assert length(x) == length(y)
    wasless = false
    for (xi, yi) in zip(x, y)
        if xi < yi
            wasless = true
        elseif xi > yi
            return false
        end
    end
    return wasless
end
```